# Is there a way I can get previous messages from a mailing list into my mailbox?

Tags: email, libreoffice, mailing-lists, mailbox, webarchive

I've just joined a certain mailing list. The list has a web archive, which is nice, but I would like to have past messages from that list - all of them or a just a few months back - in my own mailbox, as though I had been a subscriber. Preferably with the same dates, subjects and senders of the original messages.

I suppose that, in theory, perhaps all those emails could be sent to me now with a far-in-the-past send time. But - can that actually be arranged? And are there other ways to achieve this, e.g. can (web) archives be exported/converted into mbox files?

Notes:

- The list is managed by an "Mlmmj" program
- The list is also archived on mail-archive.com.
- It's the `l10n@global.libreoffice.org` list, but I'd like as general a response as is reasonable.

Comment: Does the list have an RSS feed?

Comment: @spikey_richie: Not that I am aware of, but that would be a way to go about it, for sure - use the RSS feed reading capability of my mail client (Thunderbird)

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/l10n@global.libreoffice.org/info.html possibly has an RSS feed, based on my Google-fu.

Comment: @spikey_richie: That's great! ... only 6 months back, but for my personal use case, that does the trick. Want to write the answer, or shall I?

Comment: I've turned it into an answer. P.S. The LinkedIn URL on your profile page is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at the RSS feed for that mailbox, which is available from https://www.mail-archive.com/l10n@global.libreoffice.org/info.html

This will allow you to get some or all of the previous messages, and all new messages going forward.